# Deep Comparison of unique_ptr in std::set while using operator==

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use `std::set` to hold a set of `unique_ptr`'s to a custom object I have defined. I am providing a custom compare function while defining the set (to enable deep comparison). This compare function seems to be work correctly while inserting elements into the set i.e items with equivalent content are not inserted twice.

However, if I compare two sets using `operator==`, it seems to be ignored i.e sets with equivalent elements are returned as not equal, while I expect (would like) it to be equal (as the custom compare function I am providing does a deep compare).

Is the compare function only used during insertion? If so, is there an alternative to getting `operator==` to do a deep comparison?

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks :)

Sample code

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Test

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Person {
private:
    std::string mName;

public:
    Person(const std::string& name);
    virtual ~Person() {}

    void setName(std::string& name);
    std::string getName();
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Person> PersonUniquePtr;

Person::Person(const std::string& name)
    : mName{ name }
{
}

void Person::setName(std::string& name)
{
    mName = name;
}   

std::string Person::getName()
{
    return mName;
}

bool isLess(Person* p1, Person* p2)
{
    if (p1->getName().compare(p2->getName()) == -1)
        return true;

    return false;
}

struct PersonUniquePtr_less {
    bool operator()(PersonUniquePtr const& p1, PersonUniquePtr const& p2) const
    {
        return isLess(p1.get(), p2.get());
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::set<PersonUniquePtr, PersonUniquePtr_less> personSet1;
    std::set<PersonUniquePtr, PersonUniquePtr_less> personSet2;

    PersonUniquePtr person1 = std::make_unique<Person>("Adam");
    PersonUniquePtr person2 = std::make_unique<Person>("Adam");
    personSet1.insert(std::move(person1));
    personSet1.insert(std::move(person2));
    std::cout << "personSet1.size(): " << personSet1.size() << std::endl; //Expected 1

    PersonUniquePtr person3 = std::make_unique<Person>("Bruce");
    personSet1.insert(std::move(person3));
    std::cout << "personSet1.size(): " << personSet1.size() << std::endl; //Expected 2

    PersonUniquePtr person4 = std::make_unique<Person>("Adam");
    PersonUniquePtr person5 = std::make_unique<Person>("Bruce");
    personSet2.insert(std::move(person4));
    personSet2.insert(std::move(person5));
    std::cout << "personSet2.size(): " << personSet2.size() << std::endl; //Expected 2

    std::cout << "PersonSet1:" << std::endl;
    for (auto& person : personSet1) {
        std::cout << person->getName() << std::endl;
    } //Prints out Adam Bruce

    std::cout << "PersonSet2:" << std::endl;
    for (auto& person : personSet2) {
        std::cout << person->getName() << std::endl;
    } //Prints out Adam Bruce

    bool setsAreEqual = (personSet1 == personSet2);
    if (setsAreEqual) {
        std::cout << "Sets are equal" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Sets are not equal" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BartoszKP, definitely not a duplicate, that question is about `std::set<int>` which does not use a custom comparison function, so `operator==` does the right thing. That is not the case here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++11 container requirements say that `a == b` is equivalent to

```
distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == distance(b.begin(), b.end())
&& equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin())
```

and `std::equal` does not use your custom comparison, it uses `operator==`

You can perform the comparison yourself by calling `std::equal` with a custom predicate:

```
a.size() == b.size()
&& std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
              [](PersonUniquePtr const& p1, PersonUniquePtr const& p2) {
                PersonUniquePtr_less cmp;
                return !cmp(p1, p2) && !cmp(p2, p1);
              });
```

In C++14 it's simpler because there's a new overload of `std::equal` taking four iterators, although as TemplateRex points out in a comment below, this is less efficient than testing `a.size() == b.size()` manually:

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
           [](PersonUniquePtr const& p1, PersonUniquePtr const& p2) {
             PersonUniquePtr_less cmp;
             return !cmp(p1, p2) && !cmp(p2, p1);
           });
```

In C++14 you can save some typing by using a polymorphic lambda:

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
           [](auto const& p1, auto const& p2) {
             PersonUniquePtr_less cmp;
             return !cmp(p1, p2) && !cmp(p2, p1);
           });
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using C++14 in my project and the code you have above works fine :)

Comment: IIRC, the 4-legged `std::equal` calls `std::distance` on the two pairs of bidirectional iterators (linear) whereas the set sizes are available in constant time. Wouldn't the 3-legged overload then save a pointer-chasing path over the set elements?

Comment: For `std::vector` and arbitrary subsets of bidirectional containers, the 4-legged version is efficient, right?

Comment: It's optimal for random access iterators. Not sure what you mean by arbitrary subsets of bidirectional containers. It's as efficient as possible, but no more efficient :)

Comment: I meant in case you have no precomputed sizes available.

Comment: Ah yes, in that case it's as efficient as possible, and so there's no advantage to calculating the sizes yourself and you might as well use the 4-legged version